# Get HDD (and NOT Volume) Serial Number on Vista Ultimate 64 bit

Tags: windows-vista, serial-number, hard-drive

I was once looking for getting the HDD serial number without using WMI, and I found it. [The code I found and posted on StackOverFlow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/278062/converting-hdd-serial-vb6-code-into-vb-net-code) works very well on 32 bit Windows, both XP and Vista. The trouble only begins when I try to get the serial number on 64 bit OSs (Vista Ultimate 64, specifically). The code returns String.Empty, or a Space all the time.

Anyone got an idea how to fix this?

EDIT:

I used the tools Dave Cluderay suggested, with interesting results:

Here is the output from DiskId32, on Windows XP SP2 32-bit:

```
To get all details use "diskid32 /d"
Trying to read the drive IDs using physical access with admin rights
Drive 0 - Primary Controller -  - Master drive
Drive Model Number________________: [MAXTOR STM3160215AS]
Drive Serial Number_______________: [            6RA26XK3]
Drive Controller Revision Number__: [3.AAD]
Controller Buffer Size on Drive___: 2097152 bytes
Drive Type________________________: Fixed
Drive Size________________________: 160041885696 bytes

Trying to read the drive IDs using the SCSI back door

Drive 4 - Tertiary Controller -  - Master drive
Drive Model Number________________: [MAXTOR STM3160215AS]
Drive Serial Number_______________: [            6RA26XK3]
Drive Controller Revision Number__: [3.AAD]
Controller Buffer Size on Drive___: 2097152 bytes
Drive Type________________________: Fixed
Drive Size________________________: 160041885696 bytes

Trying to read the drive IDs using physical access with zero rights

**** STORAGE_DEVICE_DESCRIPTOR for drive 0 ****
Vendor Id = []
Product Id = [MAXTOR STM3160215AS]
Product Revision = [3.AAD]
Serial Number = []

**** DISK_GEOMETRY_EX for drive 0 ****
Disk is fixed
DiskSize = 160041885696

Trying to read the drive IDs using Smart

Drive 0 - Primary Controller -  - Master drive

Drive Model Number________________: [MAXTOR STM3160215AS]
Drive Serial Number_______________: [            6RA26XK3]
Drive Controller Revision Number__: [3.AAD]
Controller Buffer Size on Drive___: 2097152 bytes
Drive Type________________________: Fixed
Drive Size________________________: 160041885696 bytes

Hard Drive Serial Number__________:             6RA26XK3

Hard Drive Model Number___________: MAXTOR STM3160215AS
```

And DiskId32 run on Windows Vista Ultimate 64-bit:

```
To get all details use "diskid32 /d"

Trying to read the drive IDs using physical access with admin rights

Trying to read the drive IDs using the SCSI back door

Trying to read the drive IDs using physical access with zero rights

**** STORAGE_DEVICE_DESCRIPTOR for drive 0 ****
Vendor Id = [MAXTOR S]
Product Id = [TM3160215AS]
Product Revision = [3.AA]
Serial Number = []

**** DISK_GEOMETRY_EX for drive 0 ****
Disk is fixed
DiskSize = 160041885696

Trying to read the drive IDs using Smart

Hard Drive Serial Number__________:

Hard Drive Model Number___________:
```

Notice how much lesser the information is on Vista, and how the Serial Number is not returned. Also the other tool, EnumDisk, refers to my hard disks on Vista as "SCSI" as opposed to "ATA" on Windows XP.

Any ideas?

EDIT 2:

I'm posting the results from EnumDisks:

On Windows XP SP2 32-bit:

```
Properties for Device 1

Device ID: IDE\DiskMAXTOR_STM3160215AS_____________________3.AAD___

Adapter Properties
------------------
Bus Type       : ATA
Max. Tr. Length: 0x20000
Max. Phy. Pages: 0xffffffff
Alignment Mask : 0x1

Device Properties
-----------------
Device Type     : Direct Access Device (0x0)
Removable Media : No
Product ID      : MAXTOR STM3160215AS
Product Revision: 3.AAD

Inquiry Data from Pass Through
------------------------------
Device Type: Direct Access Device (0x0)
Vendor ID  : MAXTOR S
Product ID : TM3160215AS
Product Rev: 3.AA
Vendor Str :



***  End of Device List  ***
```

And on Vista 64 Ultimate:

```
Properties for Device 1

Device ID: SCSI\DiskMAXTOR_STM3160215AS_____3.AA

Adapter Properties
------------------
Bus Type       : FIBRE
Max. Tr. Length: 0x20000
Max. Phy. Pages: 0x11
Alignment Mask : 0x0

Device Properties
-----------------
Device Type     : Direct Access Device (0x0)
Removable Media : No
Vendor ID       : MAXTOR S
Product ID      : TM3160215AS
Product Revision: 3.AA

Inquiry Data from Pass Through
------------------------------
Device Type: Direct Access Device (0x0)
Vendor ID  : MAXTOR S
Product ID : TM3160215AS
Product Rev: 3.AA
Vendor Str :



***  End of Device List  ***
```

Comment: Some more pieces of information that might be relevant - are the two operating systems on the same physical machine (i.e. dual boot) or separate machines? Is either a virtual machine? Anything noteworthy about the disks e.g. (RAID, etc.)?

Comment: Both OSs are on the same physical machine. No virtual machine used. Nothing special about my hard drive, a typical ATA MAXTOR 160 GB drive.

Comment: Hi again. Presumably EnumDisk1 also failed to obtain the serial number on Vista 64?

Comment: (also, did EnumDisk1 output any error information?)

Comment: No errors as far as I can remember. I pasted the whole output for EnumDisk1 here.

Comment: Shouldn't this be moved to Super User?

Answer (score 8):

This code makes three attempts at obtaining the serial number:

1. Using `IOCTL_STORAGE_QUERY_PROPERTY`.
2. Using `SMART_RCV_DRIVE_DATA`.
3. Using `IOCTL_SCSI_PASS_THROUGH`.

This code works for me on 64-bit:

```
' PhysicalDrive.vb

Option Strict On
Option Explicit On

Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports System.Text
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles

Public Class PhysicalDrive

#Region "Win32 Definitions"
    <StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)> _
    Private Structure IDEREGS
        Public bFeaturesReg As Byte
        Public bSectorCountReg As Byte
        Public bSectorNumberReg As Byte
        Public bCylLowReg As Byte
        Public bCylHighReg As Byte
        Public bDriveHeadReg As Byte
        Public bCommandReg As Byte
        Public bReserved As Byte
    End Structure

    <StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)> _
    Private Structure SENDCMDINPARAMS
        Public cBufferSize As Int32
        Public irDriveRegs As IDEREGS
        Public bDriveNumber As Byte
        <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst:=3)> _
        Public bReserved As Byte()
        <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst:=4)> _
        Public dwReserved As Int32()
        <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst:=1)> _
        Public bBuffer As Byte()
    End Structure

    <StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)> _
    Private Structure DRIVERSTATUS
        Public bDriverError As Byte
        Public bIDEError As Byte
        <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst:=2)> _
        Public bReserved As Byte()
        <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst:=2)> _
        Public dwReserved As Int32()
    End Structure

    <StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)> _
    Private Structure SENDCMDOUTPARAMS
        Public cBufferSize As Int32
        Public DriverStatus As DRIVERSTATUS
        <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst:=IDENTIFY_BUFFER_SIZE)> _
        Public bBuffer As Byte()
    End Structure

    <StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)> _
    Private Structure GETVERSIONINPARAMS
        Public bVersion As Byte
        Public bRevision As Byte
        Public bReserved As Byte
        Public bIDEDeviceMap As Byte
        Public fCapabilities As Int32
        <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst:=4)> _
        Public dwReserved As Int32()
    End Structure

    <StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)> _
    Private Structure STORAGE_PROPERTY_QUERY
        Public PropertyId As Int32
        Public QueryType As Int32
        <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst:=1)> _
        Public AdditionalParameters As Byte()
    End Structure

    <StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)> _
    Private Structure STORAGE_DEVICE_DESCRIPTOR
        Public Version As Int32
        Public Size As Int32
        Public DeviceType As Byte
        Public DeviceTypeModifier As Byte
        Public RemovableMedia As Byte
        Public CommandQueueing As Byte
        Public VendorIdOffset As Int32
        Public ProductIdOffset As Int32
        Public ProductRevisionOffset As Int32
        Public SerialNumberOffset As Int32
        Public BusType As Byte
        Public RawPropertiesLength As Int32
        <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst:=10240)> _
        Public RawDeviceProperties As Byte()
    End Structure

    <StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)> _
    Private Structure SCSI_PASS_THROUGH
        Public Length As Int16
        Public ScsiStatus As Byte
        Public PathId As Byte
        Public TargetId As Byte
        Public Lun As Byte
        Public CdbLength As Byte
        Public SenseInfoLength As Byte
        Public DataIn As Byte
        Public DataTransferLength As Int32
        Public TimeOutValue As Int32
        Public DataBufferOffset As IntPtr
        Public SenseInfoOffset As Int32
        <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst:=16)> _
        Public Cdb As Byte()
    End Structure

    <StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)> _
    Private Structure SCSI_PASS_THROUGH_WITH_BUFFER
        Public Spt As SCSI_PASS_THROUGH
        Public Filler As Int32
        <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst:=64)> _
        Public Buffer As Byte()
    End Structure

    <DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError:=True)> _
    Private Shared Function CreateFile(ByVal lpFileName As String, ByVal dwDesiredAccess As Int32, ByVal dwShareMode As Int32, ByVal lpSecurityAttributes As IntPtr, ByVal dwCreationDisposition As Int32, ByVal dwFlagsAndAttributes As Int32, ByVal hTemplateFile As IntPtr) As SafeFileHandle
    End Function

    <DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError:=True)> _
    Private Shared Function DeviceIoControl(ByVal hDevice As SafeFileHandle, ByVal dwIoControlCode As Int32, <[In]()> ByRef lpInBuffer As SENDCMDINPARAMS, ByVal nInBufferSize As Int32, <[In](), Out()> ByRef lpOutBuffer As SENDCMDOUTPARAMS, ByVal nOutBufferSize As Int32, ByRef lpBytesReturned As Int32, ByVal lpOverlapped As Int32) As Int32
    End Function

    <DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError:=True)> _
    Private Shared Function DeviceIoControl(ByVal hDevice As SafeFileHandle, ByVal dwIoControlCode As Int32, ByVal lpInBuffer As IntPtr, ByVal nInBufferSize As Int32, <[In](), Out()> ByRef lpOutBuffer As GETVERSIONINPARAMS, ByVal nOutBufferSize As Int32, ByRef lpBytesReturned As Int32, ByVal lpOverlapped As Int32) As Int32
    End Function

    <DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError:=True)> _
    Private Shared Function DeviceIoControl(ByVal hDevice As SafeFileHandle, ByVal dwIoControlCode As Int32, <[In]()> ByRef lpInBuffer As STORAGE_PROPERTY_QUERY, ByVal nInBufferSize As Int32, <[In](), Out()> ByRef lpOutBuffer As STORAGE_DEVICE_DESCRIPTOR, ByVal nOutBufferSize As Int32, ByRef lpBytesReturned As Int32, ByVal lpOverlapped As Int32) As Int32
    End Function

    <DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError:=True)> _
    Private Shared Function DeviceIoControl(ByVal hDevice As SafeFileHandle, ByVal dwIoControlCode As Int32, <[In]()> ByRef lpInBuffer As SCSI_PASS_THROUGH_WITH_BUFFER, ByVal nInBufferSize As Int32, <[In](), Out()> ByRef lpOutBuffer As SCSI_PASS_THROUGH_WITH_BUFFER, ByVal nOutBufferSize As Int32, ByRef lpBytesReturned As Int32, ByVal lpOverlapped As Int32) As Int32
    End Function

    Private Const OPEN_EXISTING As Int32 = 3
    Private Const GENERIC_READ As Int32 = &H80000000
    Private Const GENERIC_WRITE As Int32 = &H40000000
    Private Const FILE_SHARE_READ As Int32 = &H1
    Private Const FILE_SHARE_WRITE As Int32 = &H2
    Private Const FILE_SHARE_DELETE As Int32 = &H4
    Private Const SMART_GET_VERSION As Int32 = &H74080
    Private Const SMART_RCV_DRIVE_DATA As Int32 = &H7C088
    Private Const ID_CMD As Int32 = &HEC
    Private Const IDENTIFY_BUFFER_SIZE As Int32 = 512
    Private Const CAP_SMART_CMD As Int32 = &H4
    Private Const IOCTL_STORAGE_QUERY_PROPERTY As Int32 = &H2D1400
    Private Const IOCTL_SCSI_PASS_THROUGH As Int32 = &H4D004
    Private Const SCSI_IOCTL_DATA_IN As Int32 = &H1
    Private Const PropertyStandardQuery As Int32 = 0
    Private Const StorageDeviceProperty As Int32 = 0
    Private Const ERROR_INVALID_FUNCTION As Int32 = &H1
#End Region

    Public Shared Function GetSerialNumberUsingStorageQuery(ByVal diskNumber As Integer) As String
        Using hDisk As SafeFileHandle = OpenDisk(diskNumber)
            Dim iBytesReturned As Int32
            Dim spq As New STORAGE_PROPERTY_QUERY()
            Dim sdd As New STORAGE_DEVICE_DESCRIPTOR()
            spq.PropertyId = StorageDeviceProperty
            spq.QueryType = PropertyStandardQuery

            If DeviceIoControl(hDisk, IOCTL_STORAGE_QUERY_PROPERTY, spq, Marshal.SizeOf(spq), sdd, Marshal.SizeOf(sdd), iBytesReturned, 0) = 0 Then
                Throw CreateWin32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error(), "DeviceIoControl(IOCTL_STORAGE_QUERY_PROPERTY)")
            End If

            Dim result As New StringBuilder()
            If sdd.SerialNumberOffset > 0 Then
                Dim rawDevicePropertiesOffset As Integer = Marshal.SizeOf(sdd) - sdd.RawDeviceProperties.Length
                Dim pos As Integer = sdd.SerialNumberOffset - rawDevicePropertiesOffset
                While pos < iBytesReturned And sdd.RawDeviceProperties(pos) <> 0
                    result.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(sdd.RawDeviceProperties, pos, 1))
                    pos += 1
                End While
            End If
            Return result.ToString().Trim()
        End Using
    End Function

    Public Shared Function GetSerialNumberUsingSmart(ByVal diskNumber As Integer) As String
        Using hDisk As SafeFileHandle = OpenDisk(diskNumber)
            If IsSmartSupported(hDisk) Then
                Dim iBytesReturned As Int32
                Dim sci As New SENDCMDINPARAMS
                Dim sco As New SENDCMDOUTPARAMS
                sci.irDriveRegs.bCommandReg = ID_CMD
                sci.bDriveNumber = CByte(diskNumber)
                sci.cBufferSize = IDENTIFY_BUFFER_SIZE
                If DeviceIoControl(hDisk, SMART_RCV_DRIVE_DATA, sci, Marshal.SizeOf(sci), sco, Marshal.SizeOf(sco), iBytesReturned, 0) = 0 Then
                    Throw CreateWin32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error(), "DeviceIoControl(SMART_RCV_DRIVE_DATA)")
                End If
                Dim result As New StringBuilder()
                For index As Integer = 20 To 39 Step 2
                    result.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(sco.bBuffer, index + 1, 1))
                    result.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(sco.bBuffer, index, 1))
                Next
                Return result.ToString().Trim()
            Else
                Return String.Empty
            End If
        End Using
    End Function

    Public Shared Function GetSerialNumberUsingScsiPassThrough(ByVal diskNumber As Integer) As String
        Using hDisk As SafeFileHandle = OpenDisk(diskNumber)
            Dim iBytesReturned As Int32
            Dim spt As New SCSI_PASS_THROUGH_WITH_BUFFER
            spt.Spt.Length = CShort(Marshal.SizeOf(spt.Spt))
            spt.Spt.CdbLength = 16
            spt.Spt.DataIn = SCSI_IOCTL_DATA_IN
            spt.Spt.DataTransferLength = 64
            spt.Spt.DataBufferOffset = New IntPtr(Marshal.SizeOf(spt) - 64)
            spt.Spt.TimeOutValue = 60
            Dim cdb(15) As Byte
            cdb(0) = &H12 ' INQUIRY
            cdb(1) = &H1 ' EVPD bit
            cdb(2) = &H80 ' Page code (indicates Serial Number)
            cdb(4) = 64 ' Allocation length
            spt.Spt.Cdb = cdb
            If DeviceIoControl(hDisk, IOCTL_SCSI_PASS_THROUGH, spt, Marshal.SizeOf(spt), spt, Marshal.SizeOf(spt), iBytesReturned, 0) = 0 Then
                Dim iErrorCode As Int32 = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()
                If iErrorCode <> ERROR_INVALID_FUNCTION Then
                    Throw CreateWin32Exception(iErrorCode, "DeviceIoControl(IOCTL_SCSI_PASS_THROUGH)")
                End If
            End If
            Dim result As New StringBuilder()
            Dim pos As Integer = IntPtr.Size
            While pos < spt.Spt.DataTransferLength And spt.Buffer(pos) <> 0
                result.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(spt.Buffer, pos, 1))
                pos += 1
            End While
            Return result.ToString().Trim()
        End Using
    End Function

    Private Shared Function CreateWin32Exception(ByVal errorCode As Int32, ByVal context As String) As Win32Exception
        Dim win32Exception As New Win32Exception(errorCode)
        win32Exception.Data("Context") = context
        Return win32Exception
    End Function

    Private Shared Function OpenDisk(ByVal diskNumber As Integer) As SafeFileHandle
        Dim hDevice As SafeFileHandle = CreateFile(String.Format("\\.\PhysicalDrive{0}", diskNumber), GENERIC_READ Or GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ Or FILE_SHARE_WRITE Or FILE_SHARE_DELETE, IntPtr.Zero, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, IntPtr.Zero)
        If (Not hDevice.IsInvalid) Then
            Return hDevice
        Else
            Throw CreateWin32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error(), "CreateFile")
        End If
    End Function

    Private Shared Function IsSmartSupported(ByVal hDisk As SafeFileHandle) As Boolean
        Dim iBytesReturned As Int32
        Dim gvi As New GETVERSIONINPARAMS
        If DeviceIoControl(hDisk, SMART_GET_VERSION, IntPtr.Zero, 0, gvi, Marshal.SizeOf(gvi), iBytesReturned, 0) = 0 Then
            Return False
        End If
        Return (gvi.fCapabilities And CAP_SMART_CMD) > 0
    End Function

End Class
```

And here's the code to call it:

```
' MainModule.vb

Module MainModule

    Sub Main()
        Console.WriteLine("{0}-bit runtime.", IntPtr.Size * 8)
        For drive As Integer = 0 To 4
            Try
                Console.WriteLine("Drive {0}, SMART:             [{1}]", drive, PhysicalDrive.GetSerialNumberUsingSmart(drive))
                Console.WriteLine("Drive {0}, Storage Query:     [{1}]", drive, PhysicalDrive.GetSerialNumberUsingStorageQuery(drive))
                Console.WriteLine("Drive {0}, SCSI Pass Through: [{1}]", drive, PhysicalDrive.GetSerialNumberUsingScsiPassThrough(drive))
            Catch ex As Exception
                If ex.Data("Context") IsNot Nothing Then Console.Error.Write("{0} failed: ", ex.Data("Context"))
                Console.Error.WriteLine(ex.Message)
            End Try
        Next
    End Sub

End Module
```

**EDIT** - I've changed the main method to display the results of each attempt for comparison. This will hopefully illustrate how hit and miss these techniques can be.

Comment: Hi! I converted your code into C# but using SCSI PassThrough I'm getting a strange result (model number instead of serial number). I posted a question here about that and I would be plased if you can have a look at it because you probably know what's going on: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16443215/c-native-reading-hdd-serial-using-scsi-passthrough

Answer (score 3):

use DeviceIoControl with [IOCTL_STORAGE_GET_MEDIA_SERIAL_NUMBER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363411.aspx)

or check [IOCTL_CHANGER_GET_PRODUCT_DATA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363395(VS.85).aspx)

Comment: IOCTL_STORAGE_GET_MEDIA_SERIAL_NUMBER is for USB devices

Answer (score 2):

You need to ensure that your P/Invoke definitions are 64-bit friendly. Alternatively, try setting the target CPU of the projects in your solution to 32-bit. More information on P/Invoke and 64-bit can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973190.aspx).

**EDIT:**

The following rewritten code might work better for you - basically I've tidied up the P/Invoke definitions and added better error handling. The code makes two attempts to obtain the serial number. The first uses `IOCTL_STORAGE_QUERY_PROPERTY` and the second uses `SMART_RCV_DRIVE_DATA`.

```
' PhysicalDrive.vb

Option Strict On
Option Explicit On

Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports System.Text
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles

Public Class PhysicalDrive

#Region "Win32 Definitions"
    <StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)> _
    Private Structure IDEREGS
        Public bFeaturesReg As Byte
        Public bSectorCountReg As Byte
        Public bSectorNumberReg As Byte
        Public bCylLowReg As Byte
        Public bCylHighReg As Byte
        Public bDriveHeadReg As Byte
        Public bCommandReg As Byte
        Public bReserved As Byte
    End Structure

    <StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)> _
    Private Structure SENDCMDINPARAMS
        Public cBufferSize As Int32
        Public irDriveRegs As IDEREGS
        Public bDriveNumber As Byte
        <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst:=3)> _
        Public bReserved As Byte()
        <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst:=4)> _
        Public dwReserved As Int32()
        <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst:=1)> _
        Public bBuffer As Byte()
    End Structure

    <StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)> _
    Private Structure DRIVERSTATUS
        Public bDriverError As Byte
        Public bIDEError As Byte
        <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst:=2)> _
        Public bReserved As Byte()
        <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst:=2)> _
        Public dwReserved As Int32()
    End Structure

    <StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)> _
    Private Structure SENDCMDOUTPARAMS
        Public cBufferSize As Int32
        Public DriverStatus As DRIVERSTATUS
        <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst:=IDENTIFY_BUFFER_SIZE)> _
        Public bBuffer As Byte()
    End Structure

    <StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)> _
    Private Structure GETVERSIONOUTPARAMS
        Public bVersion As Byte
        Public bRevision As Byte
        Public bReserved As Byte
        Public bIDEDeviceMap As Byte
        Public fCapabilities As Int32
        <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst:=4)> _
        Public dwReserved As Int32()
    End Structure

    <StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)> _
    Private Structure STORAGE_PROPERTY_QUERY
        Public PropertyId As Int32
        Public QueryType As Int32
        <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst:=1)> _
        Public AdditionalParameters As Byte()
    End Structure

    <StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)> _
    Private Structure STORAGE_DEVICE_DESCRIPTOR
        Public Version As Int32
        Public Size As Int32
        Public DeviceType As Byte
        Public DeviceTypeModifier As Byte
        Public RemovableMedia As Byte
        Public CommandQueueing As Byte
        Public VendorIdOffset As Int32
        Public ProductIdOffset As Int32
        Public ProductRevisionOffset As Int32
        Public SerialNumberOffset As Int32
        Public BusType As Byte
        Public RawPropertiesLength As Int32
        <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst:=10240)> _
        Public RawDeviceProperties As Byte()
    End Structure

    <DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError:=True)> _
    Private Shared Function CreateFile(ByVal lpFileName As String, ByVal dwDesiredAccess As Int32, ByVal dwShareMode As Int32, ByVal lpSecurityAttributes As IntPtr, ByVal dwCreationDisposition As Int32, ByVal dwFlagsAndAttributes As Int32, ByVal hTemplateFile As IntPtr) As SafeFileHandle
    End Function

    <DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError:=True)> _
    Private Shared Function DeviceIoControl(ByVal hDevice As SafeFileHandle, ByVal dwIoControlCode As Int32, <[In](), Out()> ByRef lpInBuffer As SENDCMDINPARAMS, ByVal nInBufferSize As Int32, <[In](), Out()> ByRef lpOutBuffer As SENDCMDOUTPARAMS, ByVal nOutBufferSize As Int32, ByRef lpBytesReturned As Int32, ByVal lpOverlapped As Int32) As Int32
    End Function

    <DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError:=True)> _
    Private Shared Function DeviceIoControl(ByVal hDevice As SafeFileHandle, ByVal dwIoControlCode As Int32, ByVal lpInBuffer As IntPtr, ByVal nInBufferSize As Int32, <[In](), Out()> ByRef lpOutBuffer As GETVERSIONOUTPARAMS, ByVal nOutBufferSize As Int32, ByRef lpBytesReturned As Int32, ByVal lpOverlapped As Int32) As Int32
    End Function

    <DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError:=True)> _
    Private Shared Function DeviceIoControl(ByVal hDevice As SafeFileHandle, ByVal dwIoControlCode As Int32, <[In](), Out()> ByRef lpInBuffer As STORAGE_PROPERTY_QUERY, ByVal nInBufferSize As Int32, <[In](), Out()> ByRef lpOutBuffer As STORAGE_DEVICE_DESCRIPTOR, ByVal nOutBufferSize As Int32, ByRef lpBytesReturned As Int32, ByVal lpOverlapped As Int32) As Int32
    End Function

    Private Const OPEN_EXISTING As Int32 = 3
    Private Const GENERIC_READ As Int32 = &H80000000
    Private Const GENERIC_WRITE As Int32 = &H40000000
    Private Const FILE_SHARE_READ As Int32 = &H1
    Private Const FILE_SHARE_WRITE As Int32 = &H2
    Private Const FILE_SHARE_DELETE As Int32 = &H4
    Private Const SMART_GET_VERSION As Int32 = &H74080
    Private Const SMART_RCV_DRIVE_DATA As Int32 = &H7C088
    Private Const ID_CMD As Int32 = &HEC
    Private Const IDENTIFY_BUFFER_SIZE As Int32 = 512
    Private Const CAP_SMART_CMD As Int32 = &H4
    Private Const IOCTL_STORAGE_QUERY_PROPERTY As Int32 = &H2D1400
    Private Const PropertyStandardQuery As Int32 = 0
    Private Const StorageDeviceProperty As Int32 = 0
#End Region

    Public Shared Function GetSerialNumber(ByVal diskNumber As Integer) As String
        Dim result As String = GetSerialNumberUsingStorageQuery(diskNumber)
        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(result) Then
            result = GetSerialNumberUsingSmart(diskNumber)
        End If
        Return result
    End Function

    Public Shared Function GetSerialNumberUsingStorageQuery(ByVal diskNumber As Integer) As String
        Using hDisk As SafeFileHandle = OpenDisk(diskNumber)
            Dim iBytesReturned As Int32
            Dim spq As New STORAGE_PROPERTY_QUERY()
            Dim sdd As New STORAGE_DEVICE_DESCRIPTOR()
            spq.PropertyId = StorageDeviceProperty
            spq.QueryType = PropertyStandardQuery

            If DeviceIoControl(hDisk, IOCTL_STORAGE_QUERY_PROPERTY, spq, Marshal.SizeOf(spq), sdd, Marshal.SizeOf(sdd), iBytesReturned, 0) = 0 Then
                Throw CreateWin32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error(), "DeviceIoControl(IOCTL_STORAGE_QUERY_PROPERTY)")
            End If

            Dim result As New StringBuilder()
            If sdd.SerialNumberOffset > 0 Then
                Dim rawDevicePropertiesOffset As Integer = Marshal.SizeOf(sdd) - sdd.RawDeviceProperties.Length
                Dim pos As Integer = sdd.SerialNumberOffset - rawDevicePropertiesOffset
                While pos < iBytesReturned And sdd.RawDeviceProperties(pos) <> 0
                    result.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(sdd.RawDeviceProperties, pos, 1))
                    pos += 1
                End While
            End If
            Return result.ToString()
        End Using
    End Function

    Public Shared Function GetSerialNumberUsingSmart(ByVal diskNumber As Integer) As String
        Using hDisk As SafeFileHandle = OpenDisk(diskNumber)
            If IsSmartSupported(hDisk) Then
                Dim iBytesReturned As Int32
                Dim sci As New SENDCMDINPARAMS
                Dim sco As New SENDCMDOUTPARAMS
                sci.irDriveRegs.bCommandReg = ID_CMD
                sci.bDriveNumber = CByte(diskNumber)
                sci.cBufferSize = IDENTIFY_BUFFER_SIZE
                If DeviceIoControl(hDisk, SMART_RCV_DRIVE_DATA, sci, Marshal.SizeOf(sci), sco, Marshal.SizeOf(sco), iBytesReturned, 0) = 0 Then
                    Throw CreateWin32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error(), "DeviceIoControl(SMART_RCV_DRIVE_DATA)")
                End If
                Dim result As New StringBuilder()
                For index As Integer = 20 To 39 Step 2
                    result.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(sco.bBuffer, index + 1, 1))
                    result.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(sco.bBuffer, index, 1))
                Next
                Return result.ToString()
            Else
                Return String.Empty
            End If
        End Using
    End Function

    Private Shared Function CreateWin32Exception(ByVal errorCode As Int32, ByVal context As String) As Win32Exception
        Dim win32Exception As New Win32Exception(errorCode)
        win32Exception.Data("Context") = context
        Return win32Exception
    End Function

    Private Shared Function OpenDisk(ByVal diskNumber As Integer) As SafeFileHandle
        Dim hDevice As SafeFileHandle = CreateFile(String.Format("\\.\PhysicalDrive{0}", diskNumber), GENERIC_READ Or GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ Or FILE_SHARE_WRITE Or FILE_SHARE_DELETE, IntPtr.Zero, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, IntPtr.Zero)
        If (Not hDevice.IsInvalid) Then
            Return hDevice
        Else
            Throw CreateWin32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error(), "CreateFile")
        End If
    End Function

    Private Shared Function IsSmartSupported(ByVal hDisk As SafeFileHandle) As Boolean
        Dim iBytesReturned As Int32
        Dim gvo As New GETVERSIONOUTPARAMS
        If DeviceIoControl(hDisk, SMART_GET_VERSION, IntPtr.Zero, 0, gvo, Marshal.SizeOf(gvo), iBytesReturned, 0) = 0 Then
            Return False
        End If
        Return (gvo.fCapabilities And CAP_SMART_CMD) > 0
    End Function

End Class
```

This is the code to call it:

```
' MainModule.vb

Module MainModule

    Sub Main()
        Console.WriteLine("{0}-bit runtime.", IntPtr.Size * 8)
        For drive As Integer = 0 To 4
            Try
                Console.WriteLine("Drive {0} - serial number: [{1}]", drive, PhysicalDrive.GetSerialNumber(drive))
            Catch ex As Exception
                If ex.Data("Context") IsNot Nothing Then Console.Error.Write("{0} failed: ", ex.Data("Context"))
                Console.Error.WriteLine(ex.Message)
            End Try
        Next
    End Sub

End Module
```

I only have one 64-bit machine to test against, but this code does work on it.

Comment: A 64-bit Vista? Because I tested this code on my 64-bit Vista Ultimate and it still returns an empty string. (I use String.Trim on the result since there are additional space characters returned before the actual serial number on 32-bit OSs) No .NET code seems to have been able to return the SN. How can I get in touch with a programmer from MS to discuss this?

Comment: I tested this code on a Windows 7 RC x64 HP ML-115 server.
There are some C++ samples available, which you can download in compiled executable form. The samples I'm thinking of in particular are diskid32 (http://www.winsim.com/diskid32/diskid32.html) and EnumDisk1 (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/264203). I suggest you try running the executables on your 64-bit machine. If they are able to retrieve the serial number, maybe I or someone else can help you to implement the same techniques in your own VB.net code.

Answer (score 1):

[This code](http://read.pudn.com/downloads47/sourcecode/crypt/159311/DiskSerialNumber.cpp__.htm) should give you the hard disk serial number. It's similar (`ReadPhysicalDriveInNTWithAdminRights`) to your code you linked to but with several additional functions.

Answer (score 1):

Got working on Windows 7 64:

```
        ManagementObjectSearcher mos = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_DiskDrive");

        foreach (ManagementObject obj in mos.Get()) {
            Trace.TraceInformation("Information about disk drive {0}:", obj["Name"]);
            Trace.Indent();
            foreach (PropertyData pd in obj.Properties)
                Trace.TraceInformation("Name \"{0}\": \"{1}\"", pd.Name, pd.Value);
            Trace.Unindent();

            obj.Properties["SerialNumber"]
        }
```

Probably the class Win32_PhysicalMedia is not served on 64 bit platforms.

Even Disk32, at this time, is working (apart a bug when flipping serial number bytes), because is based on the same concepts.

Comment: I just tried this code on my machine (XP, using .NET 4.0) and accessing obj.Properties["SerialiNumber"] throws "not found" exception.

Comment: I just tried this code on my machine (XP, using .NET 4.0) and accessing obj.Properties["SerialiNumber"] throws "not found" exception.

Comment: On Windows XP you shall query Win32_PhysicalMedia. This code works on Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

Modified from the code [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/Vsexpressvcs/thread/7003d7ae-90b5-41d0-b113-67e9301c8eec):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Management;
using System.Text;

namespace Console_DiskDrive
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            String query = "SELECT * FROM Win32_DiskDrive";

            foreach (ManagementObject item in new ManagementObjectSearcher(query).Get())
            {
                string serialNumber = Convert.ToString(item["SerialNumber"]);

                Console.WriteLine(serialNumber);
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

On my system running Vista Home Premium x64, gives me a 40-character hex string that I'm assuming is my serial number. I'll open up the box and confirm later, but give that a try and see if it's what you're looking for.

Comment: I've tested that before. The WMI for getting HDD serial number has some problems, including not working on some versions of Windows and intermittent failures, so that wouldn't be the answer.

Comment: On my laptop (DELL Latitude E6400 running XP), accessing "SerialNumber" property throws "not found" exception.

Answer (score -1):

You might want to use Windows unmanaged API to do this:

call [GetVolumeInformation](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/139547) api with proper struct and find VolumeSerialNumber integer field.

This API is there for ages and was working for me since Windows 98. Unfortunately, can't check it on x64.

Can you see the correct serial number using other Windows tools?
By the way: '0' is a valid serial number! This might happen if disk image was restored from backup or something like that.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I'm not looking for Volume serial number, but the hard drive's serial number, model number, etc.