# C#/Native: Reading HDD Serial Using SCSI PassThrough

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, native, serial-number

I have written three different methods that make use of native `CreateFile` and `DeviceIoControl` calls in order to retrieve the HDD Serial Number (not the Model Number). The first one uses `S.M.A.R.T.`, the second one uses `Storage Query` and the third one uses `SCSI PassThrough`. Most of my code is based on the content of [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/782053/get-hdd-and-not-volume-serial-number-on-vista-ultimate-64-bit) (with some fixes and improvements).

Here are the results I get using [diskid32 utility](http://www.winsim.com/diskid32/diskid32.html):

```
Trying to read the drive IDs using physical access with admin rights

Drive Model Number________________: [ST975XXXXX]
Drive Serial Number_______________: [            6WS2XXXX]

Trying to read the drive IDs using physical access with zero rights

Product Id = [ST975XXXXX]
Serial Number = [6WS2XXXX]

Trying to read the drive IDs using Smart

Drive Model Number________________: [ST975XXXXX]
Drive Serial Number_______________: [            6WS2XXXX]
```

Now, here are the results using my methods:

```
S.M.A.R.T. = 6WS2XXXX
Storage Query = 6WS2XXXX
SCSI PassThrough = ST975XXXXX
```

Well... Houston we have a problem here. With the first two methods I get the correct Serial Number. With the last one I get the Model Number which is very bad. Now, here is my code:

```
--- METHOD ---

internal static String GetHardDiskSerialSCSIPassthrough(SafeFileHandle deviceHandle)
{
    IntPtr bufferPointer = IntPtr.Zero;
    String serial = String.Empty;
    UInt32 bytesReturned;

    SCSIPassthroughBuffered bspt = new SCSIPassthroughBuffered();
    bspt.SPT.Length = (UInt16)Marshal.SizeOf(bspt.SPT);
    bspt.SPT.CommandDescriptorBlockLength = 16;
    bspt.SPT.DataIn = 0x1;
    bspt.SPT.DataTransferLength = 64;
    bspt.SPT.DataBufferOffset = new IntPtr(Marshal.SizeOf(bspt) - 64);
    bspt.SPT.TimeOutValue = 60;
    bspt.SPT.CommandDescriptorBlock = new Byte[] { 0x12, 0x1, 0x80, 0x0, 64, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0 };

    Int32 bufferSize = Marshal.SizeOf(bspt);

    try
    {
        bufferPointer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(bufferSize);

        Marshal.StructureToPtr(bspt, bufferPointer, true);

        if (DeviceIoControl(deviceHandle, 0x4D004, bufferPointer, (UInt32)bufferSize, bufferPointer, (UInt32)bufferSize, out bytesReturned, IntPtr.Zero) && (bytesReturned > 0))
        {
            SCSIPassthroughBuffered result = (SCSIPassthroughBuffered)Marshal.PtrToStructure(bufferPointer, typeof(SCSIPassthroughBuffered));
            serial = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(result.Buffer, 0, result.Buffer.Length).Replace("\0", String.Empty).Trim();
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(bufferPointer);
    }

    return serial;
}

--- STRUCTURES ---

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
private struct SCSIPassthrough
{
    public UInt16 Length;
    public Byte SCSIStatus;
    public Byte PathID;
    public Byte TargetID;
    public Byte LogicalUnitNumber;
    public Byte CommandDescriptorBlockLength;
    public Byte SenseInfoLength;
    public Byte DataIn;
    public UInt32 DataTransferLength;
    public UInt32 TimeOutValue;
    public IntPtr DataBufferOffset;
    public UInt32 SenseInfoOffset;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 16)]
    public Byte[] CommandDescriptorBlock;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
private struct SCSIPassthroughBuffered
{
    public SCSIPassthrough SPT;
    public UInt32 Filler;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 64)]
    public Byte[] Buffer;
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Maybe using a wrong CDB?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code actually runs OK for me, i.e. it returns the same data as the other methods described in the referenced thread. The only change I had to make was from:

```
serial = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(result.Buffer, 0, result.Buffer.Length)
                       .Replace("\0", String.Empty)
                       .Trim();
```

To:

```
serial = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(result.Buffer, 0, result.Buffer.Length)
                       .Substring(IntPtr.Size)
                       .Replace("\0", String.Empty)
                       .Trim();
```

Comment: What kind of device do you have?

Comment: 64-bit Windows Server 2008 R2 on a HP ML115, disk is a GB0160CAABV. Even diskid32 doesn't get consistent results for all drives using these techniques - it seems to be very hit and miss from past experience.