# get hardware hard disk serial number with c++

Tags: c++, windows

I need to get the "real" hard disk serial number. I searched for different solutions without success.

I'm bulding a DLL in c++ that has to interact with another software/language.

Here's the code:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void getHDSerial( int nParams, int* pIn, int* pOut )
{
    char* command = "wmic path win32_physicalmedia get SerialNumber";
    char* hdSerial =  (char*) system(command);

        if (hdSerial) {
            GETSTRING(pOut[0]) = hdSerial;
            //  system(exit);
        }
        else {
            GETSTRING(pOut[0]) = "1";
        }
}
```

The DLL should reply the correct serial code as available in CMD using:
**wmic path win32_physicalmedia get SerialNumber**
No need to support for other OS, only windows.

Comment: How would you want that thing to work if Windows is run as a guest OS to some hypervisor, like Xen?

Comment: the client just call the DLL functions. What you mean as hypervisor?

Comment: @YuriBlanc In a hypervisor or emulator where the physical hard disk is most likely a file in the host operating system.

Comment: @RichardCritten: Even then, the VM host simulates a physical drive with actual HW properties. Just like the simulated network card has a MAC address.

Comment: But the OP wants probably some protection scheme around this idea, and it is probably useless...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/782053/get-hdd-and-not-volume-serial-number-on-vista-ultimate-64-bit

Comment: Really dosen't matter if it fails during the use of a VM. Because the application that will use that .DLL will make no sense in a VM. (audio realtime application!). My need is to get a true HD serial since the windows partition serial changes every new windows installs!